# gunicorn python application crashes from time to time

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

running

```
gunicorn -c gunicorn_config.py mainDAL:app
```

gunicorn_config.py :

```
worker_class = 'sync'
worker_connections = 1000
timeout = 960
keepalive = 2
#This is  the nuclear option. will print everything to log
spew = False
daemon = False
pidfile = "master.pid"
umask = 0
user = None
group = None
tmp_upload_dir = None
logfile = 'log_tmp.log'
errorlog = 'temp_error_log.log'
loglevel = 'info'
accesslog = 'temp_access_log.log'
proc_name = 'DAL'
# 0 is unlimited
limit_request_line = 0

def worker_exit(server, worker):
    error_stack_trace = repr(traceback.format_exc())
    if is_known_error(error_stack_trace):
        os.system('kill -TTIN  `cat master.pid`')

    print "Worker worker_exit"
    message = 'test_gunicorn_worker_exit ' + error_stack_trace
    logger.error(message)
    sentry_client.captureMessage(message)
    file = open(str(worker.pid) + '.closed', 'w+')
    file.close()
```

and from time to time my application simply crashes. i don't see and logs from the `worker_exit`

EDIT:

I've found that the `worker_exit` is printing

```
ImportError: No module named bcrypt
```

I've found out that this pip doesn't exists outside of the virtual env . 
The question is

```
1. why does the gunicorn auto restart without a a restart signal `kill -HUP`
2. why does the restart thread runs outside of the virtualenv while the the first time runs inside the virtualenv.
```

I've even ran `pip freeze |grep bcrypt` outside of the virtual env and the pip is there.

So I guess my question is to understand why does the `gunicorn` doesn't find this pip ?